# When is the image of a closed point closed under a morphism between schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism between schemes. When is the image of a closed point closed? In [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116513/x-to-y-flat-rightarrow-the-image-of-a-closed-point-is-also-a-closed-point) , some remarks were already made. For example if $X$ and $Y$ are of finite type over a field, then the image of a closed point is always closed (even if the map $f$ is not closed). On the other hand, examples like $Spec\, \mathbb{Q} \to Spec \, \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ provide us with examples of (flat, finite type) maps such that the image of a closed points is not closed.

Is there any reasonably general algebraic criterion when a morphism sends closed points to closed points if the schemes are not over a field?

Answer (score 7):

An [integral morphism](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01WG) preserves (and also reflects) closed points. This is because for an integral extension of integral domains $D \subseteq D'$ we know that $D$ is a field iff $D'$ is a field.

Besides, there are many important and well-known strengthenings:

projective $\Longrightarrow$ proper $\Rightarrow$ closed (=preserves closed subsets) $\Rightarrow$ preserves closed points