# Source is smooth if target is smooth and fibers are smooth of constant dimension

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is [Vakil 25.2 E b)](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf)

We are to show that if $\pi: X \to Y$ is a morphism of $k$-varieties with $\dim X = m > \dim Y = n$ and the scheme-theoretic fibers over closed points are smooth of dimension $m - n$, then if $Y$ is smooth, so is $X$.

We are allowed to assume Theorem 25.2.2, but I do not see how this gives us much. We need to essentially show that the sheaf of differentials $\Omega_{X/k}$ is locally free of rank $n$. We have the cotangent exact sequence

$$\pi^*\Omega_{Y/k} \to \Omega_{X/k} \to \Omega_{X/Y} \to 0$$

but it seems all that we know that the the first sheaf is locally free of rank $n$. How can we conclude?

Comment: Really, you don't see why theorem 25.2.2 is important here? That's why you know that $\Omega_{Y/k}$ is locally free of rank $n$, right? Can you apply that logic to any of the other sheaves in that exact sequence?

Comment: The issue is I do not see how the dimension of the fibers translates to information about $\Omega_{X/Y}$. Does the fibral dimension being $m-n$ tell us this sheaf is locally free of rank $m-n$? Assuming it does, we still do not have exactness on the left, so I wouldn't see how to conclude.

Comment: If you don't see that, perhaps you should reread theorem 25.2.2, especially item (ii)! And if you need exactness on the left in order to reach the desired conclusion, perhaps you should try to prove it. I've seen your attempts in other questions - I think you can get a lot further than what you've written here with some effort, and I'd be happy to help you out with an answer if you display that you've made more of an effort.

Comment: Alright, so by iv implies ii, can we say $\Omega_{X/Y}$ is locally free of rank $m - n$? Don't we need $\pi$ to be flat to say this? Then if the sequence is left exact, we could say the $\Omega_{X/Y}$, a locally free sheaf of rank $m - n$, is the quotient of $\Omega_{X/k}$ by a locally free sheaf of rank $n$, concluding. The problem is in order for this sequence to be left exact, we need $Y$ smooth (which it is) AND $\pi$ smooth, which we do not yet have. See 21.2 S. How can I get the left exactness (or do without it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me show the slightly stronger assertion that $\pi$ is smooth. As you already touched upon in the comments, there are essentially two things to show here, neither of which is trivial (at least to me): 1) that $\pi$ is flat, and 2) that $\Omega_{X/Y}$ is locally free of rank $m-n$. I never understood how the conormal sequence would help us with that, especially with 1), so I'll give a different argument.

**Part 1. We prove that $\pi$ is flat.** Let's first show that $X$ is regular, which is actually easy. Pick a closed point $x\in X$. Then $\dim\mathcal O_{X,x}=m$ by assumption, and in order for $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ to be regular, we need to show that the maximal ideal $\mathfrak m_{X,x}$ can be generated by $m$ elements. The image of $X$ under $\pi$ is a closed point $y\in Y$ (see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116513/x-to-y-flat-rightarrow-the-image-of-a-closed-point-is-also-a-closed-point/116636#116636) question). We know that $\mathcal O_{Y,y}$ is regular of dimension $n$ by assumption on $Y$, and $\mathcal O_{X,x}/\mathfrak m_{Y,y}\mathcal O_{X,x}$ is regular of dimension $m-n$ by assumption on the fibres of $\pi$. Hence $\mathfrak m_{X,x}/\mathfrak m_{Y,y}\mathcal O_{X,x}$ can be generated by $m-n$ elements, whereas $\mathfrak m_{Y,y}$ can be generated by $n$ elements. This shows that $\mathfrak m_{X,x}$ can indeed be generated by $m$ elements, as desired.

Now that we know $X$ is regular, flatness of $\pi$ follows by a miracle: Since flatness of ring extensions can be checked locally at maximal ideals, it suffices to check flatness of $\pi$ at closed points. That is, we have to check that $\mathcal O_{X,x}$ is flat over $\mathcal O_{Y,y}$ for all $x$ and $y$ as above. This follows from the following lemma.

**Lemma (miracle flatness theorem).** Let $R\rightarrow S$ be a local morphism between noetherian local $(R,\mathfrak m_R)$ and $(S,\mathfrak m_S)$. If $R$ is regular, $S$ is Cohen-Macauly, and $\dim S=\dim R+\dim S/\mathfrak mS$, then $R\rightarrow S$ is flat.

*Proof sketch.* See [Stacks Project, [Tag 00R4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00R4)] for a proof in general. However, in our concrete situation $R=\mathcal O_{Y,y}$ and $S=\mathcal O_{X,x}$, we can give a simpler proof (or rather the same proof with less technicalities). Let $f_1,\dotsc,f_n$ be generators of $\mathfrak m_R$ (the $f_i$ are necessarily a minimal system of generators since $n=\dim R=\dim Y$). As seen above, in our concrete situation we can find $g_1,\dotsc,g_{m-n}\in\mathfrak m_S$ such that the $f_i$ and $g_j$ generate $\mathfrak m_S$ (and are thus again a minimal system of generators).

We do induction on $n=\dim R$. If $n=0$, then $R$ is a field and everything is clear. So assume $n>0$. Since we've chosen minimal systems of generators, $R/f_1R$ and $S/f_1S$ are regular again of dimensions $n-1$ and $m-1$, respectively. Hence the inductive hypothesis shows that $R/f_1R\rightarrow S/f_1S$ is flat. Hence so is $R\rightarrow S$ by the slicing criterion ([Vakil, [Thm. 24.6.5](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf#7f6)]; note that the non-zero divisor hypothesis is satisfied since regular local rings are integral domains). $\square$

*What to take away from this.* There are some really cool flatness criteria: The local flatness criterion, the slicing criterion, the fibrewise criterion ([Stacks Project, [Tag 00MP](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00MP) or [Vakil, [Thm. 24.6.9](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Evakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf#7f6)]), and the miracle flatness theorem.

**Part 2. We show that $\Omega_{X/Y}$ is locally free of rank $m-n$.** For this we use the following lemma.

**Lemma.** Let $R$ be a reduced Jacobson ring and $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module. If there's an integer $d$ such that $\dim_{\kappa(\mathfrak m)}M/\mathfrak mM=d$ for all maximal ideals $\mathfrak m$, then $M$ is a locally free $R$-module of rank $d$.

*Proof.* Choose some maximal ideals $\mathfrak m$ and elements $m_1,\dotsc,m_d\in M$ whose images generate $M/\mathfrak mM$. By a version of Nakyama's lemma, there is an $f\in R\setminus \mathfrak m$ such that the $m_i$ generate $M_f$ over $R_f$. Replacing $M$ and $R$ by $M_f$ and $R_f$ (note that all maximal ideals of $R_f$ correspond to maximal ideals of $R$ by the Jacobson assumption), we may assume that the $m_i$ generate $M$. We claim that they do so freely. Indeed, if $\sum r_im_i=0$, then for every every maximal ideal $\mathfrak m'$ of $R$, the images of the $r_i$ in $\kappa(\mathfrak m')=R/\mathfrak m'$ must vanish, as $\dim_{\kappa(\mathfrak m')}M/\mathfrak m'M=d$. Hence the $r_i$ are contained in the intersection of all maximal ideals, which is $0$ since $R$ is reduced Jacobson. $\square$

To be able to apply the lemma, we must verify that $(\Omega_{X/Y})_x/\mathfrak m_{X,x}(\Omega_{X/Y})_x$ has dimension $m-n$ over the residue field $\kappa(x)$ for every closed point $x\in X$. But if $\pi(x)=y$ as above, then $(\Omega_{X/Y})_x/\mathfrak m_{Y,y}(\Omega_{X/Y})_x$ is free of rank $m-n$ over the local ring $\mathcal O_{X,x}/\mathfrak m_{Y,y}\mathcal O_{X,x}$ by assumption on the fibres of $\pi$. Hence the lemma applies and we conclude that $\Omega_{X/Y}$ is locally free of dimension $m-n$, as desired.

*What to take away from this.* Over a reduced ring $R$, a finitely generated module $M$ is already free if the vector spaces $M\otimes_R \kappa(\mathfrak p)$ have the same dimension for all $\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Spec} R$ (essentially by the same argument as above). For the same to work with only the maximal ideals, we need the technical Jacobson condition.

Comment: Another wonderful answer. I had a suspicion this was not so simple; it was starred after all.